# Simple TF2 Keras Model much slower predict and doesn't seem to train with eager execution enabled

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a very simple TensorFlow 2 Keras Model which I use in a reinforcement learning scenario. I.e. run a number of `predict` to gather experience then call `fit` to update the model, rinse and repeat:

```
input_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=(BOARD_SIZE * 3,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(BOARD_SIZE * 3 * 9, activation='relu')(input_layer)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(BOARD_SIZE * 3 * 100, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(BOARD_SIZE * 3 * 9, activation='relu')(x)
q_values = tf.keras.layers.Dense(BOARD_SIZE, activation=None, name='q_values')(x)
probabilities = tf.keras.layers.Softmax(name='probabilities')(q_values)

self.model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[probabilities, q_values])
self.model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = [None, tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()])
```

The code to predict is simply:

```
probs, q_vals = self.model.predict(input)
```

and the code to train is:

```
self.model.fit(np_inputs, {'q_values': np_targets}, verbose=0)
```

When running this scenario either with `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` or within a `with tf.Graph().as_default():` this works reasonably well.

Without that however, `predict` calls seem to be about 6 times slower, and the model does not seem to improve after calls to `fit()`.

Execution environment is TensorFlow 2.1 CPU only, Python 3.7

Example code on github: https://github.com/fcarsten/tic-tac-toe/blob/tf-2.0-migration/test_nn_q_tf2.py